# What's the best way for a UWP program to create a network share folder that can be accessed by other users?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

so i am building a UWP program where this current module needs to be able to make a network share folder that is available to all users (compatible with windows IOT device as well).

I am aware of using Powershell to do this (currently this is what i'm trying), however i want to make sure this is my best course of action.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Side note, i am building it in UWP because i wanted to make a gui for the user to build a config file which in the end would be easier for someone to understand.

Comment: TCP IP. Or find a socket library... Essentially create a meta data transmission and a stream to transfer file data. You could even host a site-let from a UWP app... using HTTP protocols.

Comment: @visc alright, i'll give it a look! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering if i did it/looking for an answer.

I ended up going the powershell route (however from what i understand, it could be done in c# as well).

here is some of my sample code

```
            using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            ps.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("Path", @"C:\path-to-folder");
            ps.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("FPath", @"C:\path-to-folder\*foldername*");

            ps.AddScript("New-Item -Path $Path -Name \"*foldername*\" -ItemType \"directory\" -Force;"); 
            ps.AddScript("New-SmbShare -Name \"*foldername*\" -Path $FPath -FullAccess Everyone");


            ps.Invoke();
        }

        var newProcessInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        newProcessInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
        newProcessInfo.Verb = "runas";
        newProcessInfo.Arguments = "net user '*CustomUserName*' '*password*' /add; net localgroup 'Administrators' '*CustomUserName*' /add";

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(newProcessInfo);
```

so what this does is add a folder and create the network share. Then it creates a local user to get around the (IIRC) UAC which can be prompted, and then makes it a member of the admin group.

The reason why i'm doing it this way is because i need a remote device to access the network share without asking the user for their account credentials, therefore making it completely hands-off